# how to fix "Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)"

Tags: r

I have a matrix of weather stations and average rainfall that I want to run a clustering algorithm on - but I am getting an error - any help very welcome please.

```
     station        avg               
[1,] "aberporth"    "12.6366666666667"
[2,] "armagh"       "12.8739130434783"
[3,] "ballypatrick" "12.3982857142857"
[4,] "bradford"     "12.3962441314554"
[5,] "braemar"      "12.025641025641" 
[6,] "camborne"     "12.2855855855856"
```

when I run this code:

```
 k2<-kmeans(na.omit(C),centers = 2,nstart=25)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in do_one(nmeth) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple errors:

1. The column `"avg"` is a string, but it has to be a numeric variable.
2. Kmeans calculates the euclidiean distance, which can only be done with numeric variables. You can not include the `"Station"` variable in your analysis.
3. Use a data.frame instead of a matrix, because the matrix can only handle one data type (character) in your example.

This is the way your would perform Kmeans Clustering:

```
df <- data.frame(
  station = c("aberporth", "armagh", "ballypatrick", "bradford", "braemar", "camborne"),
  avg = c("12.6366666666667", "12.8739130434783", "12.3982857142857", "12.3962441314554",
          "12.025641025641", "12.2855855855856")
)

    df$avg <- as.numeric(as.character(df$avg))

    kmeans(df[,2], 2, nstart=20)


K-means clustering with 2 clusters of sizes 2, 4

Cluster means:
      [,1]
1 12.75529
2 12.27644

Clustering vector:
[1] 1 1 2 2 2 2

Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
[1] 0.02814292 0.09218318
 (between_SS / total_SS =  71.8 %)

Available components:

[1] "cluster"      "centers"      "totss"        "withinss"     "tot.withinss" "betweenss"    "size"        
[8] "iter"         "ifault"
```